# How can a custom UITextView support 2 delegates - Both internal delegate and external delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a custom `UITextView`, which itself contain an internal private delegate.

```
import UIKit

class CustomTextView: UITextView {
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        
        self.delegate = self
    }
}

extension CustomTextView: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print("CustomTextView delegate textViewDidChange (Performing operation like setNeedsDisplay to implement custom drawing)")
    }
}
```

However, if I start to apply this `CustomTextView`, and applying an external delegate, it will broken because its initial internal delegate will not be executed.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var customTextView: CustomTextView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        customTextView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print("ViewController delegate textViewDidChange")
    }
}
```

If we execute the above code, only

```
ViewController delegate textViewDidChange
```

will be printed.

I was wondering, what are some good design, to ensure multiple delegates are supported, so that both will be printed?

```
CustomTextView delegate textViewDidChange (Performing operation like setNeedsDisplay to implement custom drawing)
ViewController delegate textViewDidChange
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe you may keep your internal delegate and inside the method call a callback. Then when you need to use external delegate, you access it from callbak.

Comment: You need an external delegate property, and your internal delegate must forward calls to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a custom other delegate property and forward calls to it with the internal delegate

```
class CustomTextView: UITextView {
    weak var other:UITextViewDelegate?
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)! 
        self.delegate = self
    }
}

extension CustomTextView: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print("CustomTextView delegate textViewDidChange (Performing operation like setNeedsDisplay to implement custom drawing)")
        other?.textViewDidChange?(textView)
    }
}
```

Then

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    customTextView.other = self
}
```

Comment: Also, he need to set other delegate to VC.
customTextView.other = self

Comment: Hahaha :D at least you changed it

Comment: Thanks. I guess the `other` should be weak?

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomTextView: UITextView {

    var callback: (() -> Void)?

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)! 
        self.delegate = self
    }
}

extension CustomTextView: UITextViewDelegate {
    func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print("CustomTextView delegate textViewDidChange (Performing operation like setNeedsDisplay to implement custom drawing)")
        self.callback?()
    }
}
```

And your ViewController to welcome callback.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var customTextView: CustomTextView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        customTextView.callback = { 
           print("ViewController delegate textViewDidChange")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this won't cover different usages of other delegate methods as `callback` will be generic for any other addition

Comment: You're right. But I just wanted to show a different approach. Also, I don't know why but having 2 delegate not seemed correct to me.